# Identifying the quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G = {R,+},H = {Z}. R is all real and Z is all integers.

How would I be able to identify the quotient group in this case. 
I know the quotient group is the set of all right cosets unsure of how to determine these.
Thanks

Comment: $G$ is *all* reals, not all positive reals, with addition as the law of combination.

Answer (score 2):

For $x \in \mathbb R$, there is a unique $r \in [0, 1)$ such that $x \in r+\mathbb Z$ (in fact, $r = x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$).

Addition is "modulo $1$" - for example, $(0.25+\mathbb Z)+(0.5+\mathbb Z) = 0.75+\mathbb Z$, and $(0.75+\mathbb Z)+(0.75+\mathbb Z) = 1.5+\mathbb Z = 0.5+\mathbb Z$.